# Making list header <div> display consistently as <ol> list

Tags: css, html, html-lists, anchor

Can anybody help me correct this: http://jsfiddle.net/ShgRr/ so that the div displays it's content consistently with the ol?

The main problem is that the right-positioned span is breaking outside the div.

I did consider making the div a li item but that would obviously be un-semantic.

Something else I was wondering - is it correct to use negative margin on an anchor so it covers the li bullet and makes the whole link clickable?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Why use a `<div>`? Your CSS will work just fine if you move the contents into a new `<li>` with that class name: http://jsfiddle.net/ShgRr/2/

I'd argue that making the `<div>` an `<li>` is perfectly fine. `<table>` elements contain both table headers and table rows without problems.

Comment: The problem there is that there are 5 list items numbered 1-5. If the list name is also a list item, the 5 actual items will be numbered 2-6.

Comment: You can use [CSS counters](http://www.impressivewebs.com/css-counter-increment/) to implement a proper counter.

Comment: That's interesting - I wasn't aware of CSS counters. However, I'm still reluctant to make the div a li as it isn't a list item. If lists had an equivalent to th, I would definitely use that. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

"is it correct to use negative margin on an anchor so it covers the li bullet and makes the whole link clickable?"

it is more correct to remove the bullet entirely if you don't want it there.

if you do want ti these - I don't tend to make bullets themselves clickable - they're a very small target compared to whatever they're bulleting. Easier to click the text than the bullet

Comment: I do want it there and I need the entire list to be clickable. If you see the fiddle, you'll see I am using li:hover to change the li background color. But without the negative margin on the anchor, the li bullet is not clickable despite the background color changing.

Answer (score 0):

your can add this class in your CSS, html part

```
    div a  span > i
    {
        margin: 0 8px;
    }
```